# FastAPI/Pydantic accept arbitrary post request body?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic, starlette

I want to create a FastAPI endpoint that just accepts an arbitrary post request body and returns it.

If I send `{"foo" : "bar"}` , I want to get `{"foo" : "bar"}` back. But I also want to be able to send `{"foo1" : "bar1", "foo2" : "bar2"}` and get that back.

I tried:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

app.post("/")
async def handle(request: BaseModel):
    return request
```

But that returns an empty dictionary, no matter what I send it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accepted answer works as long as the input is wrapped in a dictionary. That is: started with a `{` and ends with a `}`. However, that does not cover all valid JSON inputs. For example, the following valid JSON inputs would fail:

- `true` / `false`
- `1.2`
- `null`
- `"text"`
- `[1,2,3]`

In order to have a truly generic JSON input accepted by the endpoint, the following would work:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict, List, Union
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def handle(request: Union[List,Dict,Any]=None):
    return request
```

Just using `Any` did not work for some reason. When I used it, FastApi was expecting the input from the query arguments, not from the request body.

The `=None` makes it accept `null` and also an empty body. You can leave that part off and then the request body will be required to be not empty/null.

If you are using Python3.10 then you can get rid of the `Union` and write the definition as:

```py
async def handle(request: List | Dict | Any = None):
```

Comment: shouldn't `Any=None` be enough? I mean, why isn't `List/Dict` covered in `Any`?

Comment: See the paragraph below the code example. That should answer your question.

Comment: Aah.. I missed that (for some reason)

Answer (score 19):

You can use type hint Dict[Any, Any] to tell FastAPI you're expecting any valid JSON:

```py
from typing import Any, Dict
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def handle(request: Dict[Any, Any]):
    return request
```