# FastAPI post does not recognize my parameter

Tags: python, curl, fastapi, http-status-code-422

I am usually using Tornado, and trying to migrate to FastAPI.

Let's say, I have a very basic API as follows:

```py
@app.post("/add_data")
async def add_data(data):
    return data
```

When I am running the following Curl request:
`curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/add_data -d 'data=Hello'`

I am getting the following error:

`{"detail":[{"loc":["query","data"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

So I am sure I am missing something very basic, but I do not know what that might be.

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you are sending a ***string data***, you have to specify that in the router function with *typing* as

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Payload(BaseModel):
    data: str = ""


@app.post("/add_data")
async def add_data(payload: Payload = None):
    return payload
```

Example cURL request will be in the form,

```
curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:6022/add_data"  -d '{"data":"Hello"}'
```

Comment: Thank you it works! 
I am however a bit confused why I need to define a BaseModel for post API but not get.

Comment: In your get request, the data are being sent as ***query parameters*** whereas here as ***payload***

Comment: And you don't have to hard-code input parameters (such as `data` field in `Payload`), see how to pass and receive any dict or JSON, without having to predefine its keys: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879659/9962007

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you passing a form data to your endpoint. To process it, you need to install python-multipart via pip and rewrite your function a little:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/add_data')
async def process_message(data: str = Form(...)):
    return data
```

If you need json data, check Arakkal Abu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

[FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body) advise this solution for strings in body:

- just add `Body()`, like `data: str = Body()`.

Complete example:

```
from fastapi import Body

@app.post("/add_data")
async def add_data(data: str = Body()):
    return data
```

That tells FastAPI that the value is expected in body, not in the URL.